# "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1" when the size of the array > the index

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

```
public static int[] allBetween()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int first;
        int last;

        System.out.println("Enter the first number");
        first = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the last number");
        last = input.nextInt();

        int[] between = {((last - first) + 1)};

        for(int count = 0; count <= (last - first); count++)
        {
            between[count] = (first + count);
        }

        return between;
    }
```

I'm a little rusty and I dont't see the issue here, I have tried manually assigning the size of the array to 100 and first and last to 1 and 5 but it still returns the same error.

any ideas?

this is my first post on stack over flow, Please correct me if I'm posting in an incorrect manner

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your post, but before you post about runtime errors you should probably debug more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below statement:

```
int[] between = {((last - first) + 1)};
```

initializes the array with just a single element, with the value - `last - first + 1`

Change it to:

```
int size = last - first + 1;
int[] between = new int[size];
```

And then, you can change your loop to:

```
for(int count = 0; count < size; ++count)
```

Answer (score 3):

Issue is:

```
int[] between = {((last - first) + 1)}; //initializes array with value
```

You have only one value in this array at index 0, and if `last-first` is greater than ZERO, you will end up having `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Read [arrays tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

you should replace

```
int[] between = {((last - first) + 1)};
```

with

```
int[] between = new int[((last - first) + 1)];
```

because your version always creates an array of length 1. See this for example:

```
int[] foo = {22};
```

is an `int[]` of length 1 and `foo[0]` is `22`. Whereas

```
int[] bar = new int[33];
```

createas an array of length 33 where each index stores the default value `0`.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
int[] between = {((last - first) + 1)};
```

creates an array with a single element whose *value* is equal to `((last - first) + 1`.

Use:

```
int[] between = new int[(last-first)+1];
```

anyway, to iterate through it, you can use a nicer more readable/idiomatic construct:

```
for(int count = 0; count < between[length]; count++)
{
    between[count] = (first + count);
}
```

Remember that arrays are addressed and dimensioned by brackets, created explicitly with braces.

Also, `between[count] = (first + count);` looks suspicious. Make sure that's really what you want it to do, namely to set the `count`<sup>th</sup> element  of `between` to `first+count`. That would just make an array filled with `first, first+1, ...`.